# python program for multiple threded echo handler using time.delay function

Tags: python

could any one help out with the code for below question

```
Write a multi-threaded Echo Handler in Python.
```

Each Thread should be able to deal with a connection from a client, while other threads deal with connections from other clients concurrently.
To test, use time.sleep() calls to ensure concurrency.
Use 3 to 5 threads.
Each thread should deal with a different port number.

i tried the following code:

```
  ` #!/usr/bin/python


   import socket


    import thread


    import time


     def Child_thread(clientsocket, (ip,port), id ):


    data = "anonymous data"
    print "Client with ID %d is now alive" %id
    while len(data) > 0:
    data = clientsocket.recv(2048)
    print "data received from client with ID %d" %id
    print "Data recieved is %s" %data
    clientsocket.send(data)
    print "Closing the connection.... of client with ID %d" %id
    print "and port number %d" %port
    clientsocket.close()
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind( ("0.0.0.0", 8001) ) 
    sock.listen(2) 
    for i in range(5):
    print "Server is listening for clients"  
    (clientsocket, (ip,port) )  =  sock.accept()
    print "received connection from %s" %ip
    print "Received connection from port number %d" %port
    print "Starting Echo Server"
    thread.start_new_thread(Child_thread, (clientsocket, (ip,port), (i,)))
    time.sleep(10)
    print "Server is shutting down"
    sock.close()`
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Here at SO we solve problems programmers face, not prepare code for their laziness.

Comment: i tried the following code:

Comment: Where is the code? I can't see it... Atleast provide some snippet, where you are facing problem.

Comment: I am not able to send the code in the comment box.

Comment: You can edit your question. Just place your code in your question itself :)

Comment: I included the code in the question

Comment: I just wanted to know whether is there any other way of changing the code to provide same solution that is for multi threaded echo handler using time.delay function for different ports

Answer (score 0):

[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) is an event driven networking engine you might want to have a look at. See if it can solve your problem.

Comment: so could you tell me with example how would i implement twisted in the same question.

Comment: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Documentation Check out the howtos and examples given in docs and also check the FAQ's. I guess that might help you out.